# Excel dropdown doesn't store names with Apostrophe

Tags: excel

I have created an excel application where it pulls the data from the database depending on the "name" selected from a drop-down. But, the drop down in excel doesn't have the option to have **Apostrophe** in names whereas the database has stored the names with apostrophe. Is there any way that I could hard code the names in the  excel dropdown with apostrophe ?

Much appreciate your help !

Comment: It would depend on your code which you haven't posted so ... maybe?

Comment: How are you populating the drop down now?  Data  Validation List, Form Combo box ?

Comment: I am linking the drop down to another worksheet that has list of names. Now I copied the name from database and pasted it to the drop down. It works fine. But when I manually type in the name with Apostrophe it stops the execution and throws up the error code at  "dbs.execute sql"

Comment: you should show the code for the dbs.execute.   My Guess is that when you manually type in the name you are not changing the Apostrophe to Chr(39)